# Dynamically select catalog for Tomcat mysql connection pool in a Spring application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, catalog

I need to create a connection pool from a spring application running in a tomcat server.
This application has many catalogs, the main catalog (its is static) called 'db' has just one table with all existing catalog names and a boolean flag for the "active" one.

When the application starts I need to choose from the main catalogs the active one, then I have to select it as default catalog.

How can I accomplish this?

Until now I used a custom class `DataSourceSelector extends DriverManagerDataSource` but now I need to improve the db connection using a pool, then I thought about a tomcat dbcp pool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@Configuration
public class DataAccessConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db");
        ds.setUsername("javauser");
        ds.setPassword("");
        ds.setInitialSize(5);
        ds.setMaxActive(10);
        ds.setMaxIdle(5);
        ds.setMinIdle(2);
        ds.get
        return ds;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Extend `BasicDataSourceFactory` to produce customized `BasicDataSource`s.
2. Those customized `BasicDataSource`s would already know which catalog is active and have the `defaultCatalog` property set accordingly.
3. Use your extended `BasicDataSourceFactory` in the Tomcat configuration.

Comment: Would be an alternative to configure the datapool programmatically at startup?

Comment: Your end result should be `BasicDataSource` with the right `defaultCatalog`. The only way to get this object (as far as I know) is to tweak the factory. If you can manage to achieve this differently, then fine. But I am not aware of different approaches.

Comment: Maybe I found this solution (view my answer) howevery I can not understand if this use the same tomcat dbcp or not...

Comment: In your answer you are simply creating data source manually, but you are not using the pool. Pool does *much* more - it releases connections when they're not used, keeps a certain number open and so on. See DBCP [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) for more details.

Comment: For example this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Plain_Ol%27_Java seems to have all pool properties... not just a datasource.